# Default initialization of buillt-in members

Tags: c++, c++11

On Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition, 17.6.3.1 it is stated that

> The  ‘‘default  initialization’’ of a built-in  member  leaves that 
>   member  uninitialized.

referring to the default compiler generated constructor.

However, in 17.6.2 we have the following code

```
struct S {
  string a;
  int b;
};

S f(S arg)
{
  S s0 {};     // default construction: {"",0}
..
}
```

where b is default initialized to 0.

So, what am I missing here ?

Comment: @JonAnderOrtizDurántez I'm not doing any compilation. I suppose it should be true for any compiler.

Comment: `S s0;` would be [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

Comment: Doesn't the book explain that?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sure it explains it, but doubting is part of the process of reading, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing "[aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)," not default initialization.  And within aggregate initialization, unspecified members undergo value initialization (e.g. zero for integers).